# FBSDKcorekit shared application is unavailable

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using Pod and all are the lastest version
Using

```
Pod onesignal 
Pod facebook login
Target ‘onesignalnotificationextention’do
Pod ‘onesignal’
end
```

Onesignal is an notification service extension 
Facebooklogin is working when onesignal are removed 
But it give this error when both are used

> **‘sharedapplication’ is unavailable:not available on ios(app extension) -use view controller based solutions where appropriate**

How to solve this?
Error in code
This is in FBSDKAppEvent.m

```
Uiviewcontrollwr *vc =[uiapplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewcontroller.presentedViewcontroller;
```

please help, i can't find anything?

Answer (score 0):

so i solved this problem
the problem was that i only 
set
 `require only App-Extension-Safe Api to no`
in myproject.xcodeproe and the targets
it seemed the all the facebook pods were to yes
so i have to set no for all xcodeproject,target,all facebook pods
you can find `require only App-Extension-Safe Api`
in build setting for pods,target,and project
important note when ever you reinstall pods they are reseted to yes